# Trying to implement momentjs to display localtime

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Before asking this question I have searched all stackoverflow and read the docs but I can't just understand how to convert one UTC date to local time of an user and display it in his format. I keep trying different methods but I keep getting the same time again and again.

so my django returns obj.created_on in UTC as - 2013-12-26T13:52:24 - no timezone Info here but I know its UTC

Now I want momentjs to auto detect the user's timezone and convert it in that timezone.

Can I have proper syntax for the same?

I was trying this as well:

```
new_date = moment(obj.created_on).utc().local().format()
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Moment has two different `utc` functions:

- One is [on a moment instance](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/utc/), used to switch the mode to UTC.

  ```
  moment(input).utc()
  ```
- The other is [on the moment prototype](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/), used to interpret the input as already in UTC.

  ```
  moment.utc(input)
  ```

So, you want this syntax:

```
moment.utc(obj.created_on).local().format()
```

Answer (score 2):

```
moment($('#start').val()).utc().format("ddd, DD MMMM YYYY H:mm:ss");
moment($('#end').val()).utc().format("ddd, DD MMMM YYYY H:mm:ss");
```

will display Date format in UTC if you want the date in local format.

```
moment($('#start').val()).utc().local().format("ddd, DD MMMM YYYY H:mm:ss");
moment($('#end').val()).utc().local().format("ddd, DD MMMM YYYY H:mm:ss");
```

Default will take as GMT time. We need to convert that into our local format.